# unity doesn't show preview

Tags: unity-game-engine

My question is quite simple. I am learning Unity and watching a tutorial about making a 2D game.

In the tutorial, there is a `Preview` section at the bottom right corner. But in my Unity, there is nothing there. There is `Inspector` on the right and below of `Add Component` there is nothing.

Can anyone explain to me how can I activate that part? Thanks in advance!

This is what I want: [image]

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This preview box is for resources. It shows a preview of the resource. To get this to show up you must click on one of your resources(Like an image).

[image: Preview box]

However when you do not have a resource selected it will not show up

[image: Preview box does not show when nothing is selected]

Comment: Ah, okay. When I click to the something like image in the assets folder, it works. But when I click an object in the hierarchy, it doesn't work. Is it normal?

Comment: @kalahari I believe so.

Comment: But in tutorial, when he clicks an object in the hierarchy, it is shown in the preview too, I checked just now.

Comment: What does he click on? A 3D model? A texture?

Comment: A 2D object which has got an animation and it is also a prefab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65998/discussion-between-noah-huppert-and-kalahari).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a little too late but in order to get the model to show up:

1. Right click on the little model figure on the bottom right corner of the Preview window
2. Click on Select Other ...
3. Select my prefab
4. You should be able to hit the Play bttn to see your animation afterwards

FYI I'm currently on Unity 2019.2.17f1